# Advanced Custom Fields from Category - IF statement

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Please if someone could help ill be very greatful.

I know how to use the if statement using *Advanced Custom Fields* on posts - but this time I want to pull the value from the *Advanced Custom Fields* in the category, I have managed to put this code together - but can't work out how to make it an if statement.

This code pulls the value from the category custom field - how can i convert it to if value empty do "X" if true do "Z"

```
<?php
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $taxonomy       = $queried_object->taxonomy;
    $term_id        = $queried_object->term_id;
    the_field( 'logo_src', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id );
?>
```

My failed attempt:

```
<?php
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $taxonomy       = $queried_object->taxonomy;
    $term_id        = $queried_object->term_id;
    if ( get_field('logo_src', 'true', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id ) ) {
?>
  do x 
<?php } else { ?>
   do z 
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `the_field` echoes, you have to use `get_field`.

Comment: Hi Thanks alot - well - im not longer getting a php error - but it dont work?

Comment: `
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object(); $taxonomy =        $queried_object->taxonomy; $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
if  (get_field('logo_src', 'true', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id)) {?>
do x
<?php } else {?>
do z
<?php }?>`

Comment: @Milo can you help?

Comment: If (empty ( $value )) { } else { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

However your parameters for [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) are incorrect in your example. The second value should be an ID or `false` (`true` is not valid):

```
// Incorrect. Uses 'true' as second parameter:
if ( get_field('logo_src', 'true', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id ) ) {
```

Try this. Use `get_field()` to return the value of the field in your conditional statement argument. Use [`the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) to print the value of the field:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$taxonomy       = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id        = $queried_object->term_id;

if ( get_field( 'logo_src', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id ) )
{
    the_field( 'logo_src', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id );
}
else
{
    echo 'Nope.';
}
```